# VS code in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am looking to see if it's possible to run vs code from a jupyter notebook, as in have it as a kernel that I can use to run vs code in the web browser.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/vscode/

Is this even possible?

So have what appears in anaconda navigator below, appear in the jupyter lab ui below.

[image: Jupyter Navigator]

[image: Jupyter Lab]

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-monaco (a full answer would probably include installation instruction, as this is not a small feat).

Comment: Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this.

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-monaco

Although it's "merely a 'proof-of-concept' implementation and nowhere near production status" so not ready for my use case yet. Still it's there for those interested.